# Integrating Jssor Slider with E-Smart Zoom

Tags: jquery, jssor, zooming

I am using Jssor slider and it works perfectly; however I want to integrate the zoom effect for the current slide. The zoom works perfectly for the first slide however it doesn't function for the second one.

**Jquery code to initiate the zoom:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#imageFullScreen').smartZoom({'containerClass':'zoomableContainer'});
  });
```

**HTML Code for the slider:**

```
   <div  u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
        <img u="image" src="img/alila/01.jpg" id="imageFullScreen"/>
        <img u="thumb" src="img/alila/thumb-01.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img u="image" src="img/alila/02.jpg" id="imageFullScreen" />
        <img u="thumb" src="img/alila/thumb-02.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Source:**

Zoom:
http://e-smartdev.com/#!jsPluginList/panAndZoomJQuery

Slider: http://www.jssor.com/

**EDIT:**

I tried giving images different `"id"` and include these js command `$('#imageFullScreen_for1').smartZoom()` and `$('#imageFullScreen_for2').smartZoom()` // just dummy the actual ones are names as #one, #two & so on..

As expected the first one works well however the second image disappears when double clicked for zoomin & zoomout effect.

http://sociomarker.com/websites/demo/

Comment: Good work and good question. I had a look and it worked well. I think there is a bug in 'smart-zoom' library.

Comment: @jssor Consider a upvote if you find it good. Is there any alternative zoom library that you can suggest for the output I am looking to achieve?

Comment: I am not familiar with zoom libraries. Please just try some others if you have. As it's not difficult to fix it, you can contact the developer.